# OpenGL/JOGL: How to retrieve the position and orientation of a geometric object

Tags: opengl, position, orientation

In an educational software (JOGL) I have a hierarchical structure of several rotations and translations that moves a geometric shape (let's say a box) to a point in space.

I can calculate the position and the orientation of the object after translations and rotations using some basic math, but I also want to know if there is a way to read this data directly from OpenGL/JOGL?

The idea is students can see that the calculated position/orientation is equal to the real one (Coming from opengl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I also want to know if there is a way to read this data directly from OpenGL/JOGL?

OpenGL is not a scene graph, it just draws points, lines and triangles to a framebuffer, then forgets about the vertices you've supplied. As of such there's not even the trace of the sort of data structure to do this.

Or short: OpenGL doesn't work that way you (may) think it does and there's no such function to retrieve the information you seek, because that's not how OpenGL works.